# Django. hosting python 3.4 django 1.8

Tags: django, hosting

Посоветуйте хороший хостинг, подходящий под версии из темы. Зачастую поддержку оказывают питону версии 2.7... если использовать такие хостинги, то возникнут ли проблемы в работе? ( вообще работать будет? ) и если какие-то части кода изменить под 2.7 в процессе работы на хостинге, то обеспечит ли это работоспособность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам нужен именно хостинг, то вроде бы python 3 поддерживается на [hostfabrica.ru](http://hostfabrica.ru/) и [sweb.ru](https://help.sweb.ru/entry/150/)
Но на любом хостинге Вы в любом случае будете сильно ограничены в настройках и возможностях (захотите поставить redis в качестве кэша, mongodb или что-то еще - сразу придется переходить на VPS/VDS). Плюс там всегда следят, чтобы процессор и память поменьше использовали - превысите лимит - и ищите другой хостинг (а django достаточно требовательна к ресурсам).

Поэтому рекомендую либо VPS (например, [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) - минимальный тариф $5 / месяц, но если ставите redis, берите сразу за $10 - на 512 мб редис даже тесты не проходит), либо облачный хостинг (самый популярный сейчас - [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)). На digitalocean есть хорошая база данных, и там можно легко найти инструкции по развертыванию сервера на VPS (не только для digitalocean), например, [вот эта](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

UPD: из хостингов есть еще [locum](http://locum.ru/)

Comment: я так понимаю VPS дает возможность устанавливать все что угодно и настраивать сервер как мне нужно?

Comment: Именно так. Это как полноценный компьютер (сервер), на котором можете делать, что хотите (в рамках закона страны, где расположен vps + правил хостера). Плюс легко расширяется - можете расширить память/дисковое пространство, выбрав другой тариф.